# Understanding the Jacobian - meaning of columns - best linear approximation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am trying to get my head around the Jacobian matrix I suppose.

If we have a map $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ in variables $x_1,\dots x_n$ we can form the Jacobian matrix:

$$J=(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)_{ij}$$
1) **Why do we hope that this has rank $n$?** I understand that each column is a vector encoding how that position of the function behaves under the first derivative(with respect to each variable).

I.e. column one is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}\\\vdots\\\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}\end{pmatrix}$$ 
and thus is there is dependence, the tangent space should be lacking information in some way.

2) If we evaluate this at some point that is continuously differentiable, say $a$ i.e. evaluate $J(a)$, we are meant to be able to use this as the best linear approximation near $a$. **How would we use this?** Compute $J(a)$ and obtain a matrix $J(a):\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ and multiply this by what?

---

Example: If I map $\Bbb R^1\to \Bbb S^1$ via $f(x)=(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ I can take $f:(0,\frac\pi2)\mapsto $ the first quarter arc of the circle (counterclockwise) (open arc) - with Jacobian:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(x)\\\cos(x)\end{pmatrix}$$ and I have a vector $(-\sin(x),\cos(x))$, what good does that do me? **I can write this vector as a tangent to my circle by translating it from the origin to my point?**

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly clarification, need not address all your concerns.

1) Why do we hope that this has rank n?

> ... column 1 is $ (\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} \ldots \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1})^T $ and thus is there is dependence

Our concern here is **linear dependence** not just dependence. For instance, $ x^2 $ and $ x^4 $ are obviously dependent but not linearly.

2) How would we use this (Jacobian matrix)?

First, Jacobian matrix is not approximation for any function as you guessed, but a matrix gives us a linear transformation, we are talking about using this linear transformation (usually called differential) as a linear approximation. Also differential is not the (local) linear approximation for the original function, but

> It’s the best linear approximation to the change in the (original) function’s value near the point

as pointed out by @amd in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945866) to the question *How is the Jacobian the derivative if they have different dimensions*. There, he explains it well with examples. The differential of $ \Delta(x) $ is $ J(a)\Delta(x) $. So, we are basically multiplying the Jacobian with displacement $ \Delta(x) $.

I hope this helps. Thank you.